# How do you disable links, pages and references in a WebView?

Tags: java, android, class, webview

I have a Web View in Android,and I open a html web page in it.But it's full of links and images,and when I click one of them,it loads in my webview. So I want to disable this behavior,so if I click on a link,don't load it. I've tried this solution and edited a bit for myself, but not worked.
Please give me a solution with full code. I'm new to Java and Android.

My Full code here:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressBar progressBar;
    WebView webView;
    String url="http://example.com";
    TextView textView;
    //to hide progressbar after loading part 1
    LinearLayout liProgressContainer;
    private String currentUrl;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvLoadingPercentage);
        //to hide progressbar after loading part 2
        liProgressContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.liProgressContainer);
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {

                progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                textView.setText(progress + " %");
            }
        });
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        WebSettings browserSetting = webView.getSettings();
        browserSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl(url);


    }

    //back button function
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            liProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            liProgressContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            //hide header part
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your shouldOverrideUrlLoading method in your MyWebViewClient class to only load a URL should it match your desired URL. Add a field to your MyWebViewClient class to store a URL and add a single-arg constructor.

```
private String desiredUrl;

public MyWebViewClient(String url) {
    this.desiredUrl = url;
}
```

In your shouldOverrideUrlLoading method, check to see if the supplied URL is equal to your URL instance variable.

```
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (desiredUrl.equals(url))
        view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}
```

When setting your web view client, pass your URL argument, e.g.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient(url));
```

Comment: Thank you for answer..I tried ...but it didn't work...Please can you add your newly codes into my code and paste it to comment...Thank you....